# If function returning FALSE from blank cells

Tags: excel

Ok, not sure if its the late night or tiredness but I can't find what's going wrong with this IF function.

```
=IF(B36="yes",F4+6,F4), IF(AND(B36="yes",C36="yes"),F4,F4+6)
```

It works fine except when both B36 and C36 cells are empty, when this happens I need it to display the info from Cell F4, but it just comes up FALSE.
Any ideas?

Comment: I do not understand how the formula you supplied is working. You cannot simply stack up two stand-alone formulas like that separated by a comma. You need to nest them. Are the only possible values either Yes or *blank*? If not, what is to be done if those occur?

Comment: The formula that you have posted will return #VALUE!  If you are certain this is the correct formula, please post a copy of your workbook at some file sharing site, and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and had a similar problem.  I suggest you break it into parts and handle each part separately. Also, if I read it correctly, it looks like you have four comma separated items in an if statement that requires only three items.  If statements require a logical statement, then a comma followed by the value if true, then a comma followed by the value if false.  Check that out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to nest the second if function, hence your are not getting the expected result. Could you please explain more about what you exactly trying to do?

FYR => http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php

Answer (score 0):

Use just:

=IF(AND(B36="yes",C36="yes"),F4,F4+6)

Why you need to use  "=IF(B36="yes",F4+6,F4)," this part.